# Push method with new Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to push some element in a 2-D empty Array, and I find some problem with the push method.

```
var a = [[],[],[]]; 
a[1].push(1);
console.log(a);
//result: [ [], [ 1 ], [] ]
```

The above code will get the correct result, but the push method always push to all index if I use new Array method. Did I do something wrong with it?

```
var a = new Array(3).fill([]);
// a = [[], [], []]  
a[1].push(1);
console.log(a);
//result: [ [ 1 ], [ 1 ], [ 1 ] ], 
//but I think it should be [ [], [ 1 ], [] ] if I only push 1 to a[1]
```

Comment: what result you are waiting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first snippet creates 3 different sub-arrays and stores them in `a` at `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`. When you modify `a[1]`, `a[0]` and `a[2]` are not effected.

The second snippet creates 1 sub-array and stores it in `a` 3 times at `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`. When you modify `a[1]`, `a[0]` and `a[2]` are modified too because they all hold the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Used like this, fill() puts your value in every indexes in your array. To use it as you want, you should try `fill(value, start, end)` where start is the first index you want to fill with value, and end is the last.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill): The fill() method fills all the elements ... with a static value.

Comment: But the problem here is once fill is used he should be allowed to change the individual elements